# Finding volume element in a wave function

Tags: wave-equation

[image]

Im working on wave function. I dont know how to find this volume element from the figure eventhough some explanation for factors under the figure . Any help? [ In that paper, the author used $(s,t,u)$ as coordinates, where $s=r_1+r_2, t=r_2-r_1, u=r_{12}$]